# Get real position in lexer. Added example

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, antlr4

I writing editor with netbeans7 and ANTLR4
I have line in my.g4 file

```
Label       : {(getCharPositionInLine()==0)}? ID;
```

That works well for static files, but while editing getCharPositionInLine() returns 0 often in other places.
How get a real position in lexer?

updated
I created example with this problem
https://github.com/daimor/SimpleANTLR

Comment: Your observation *"returns 0 often in other places"* can't be reproduced by the limited amount of code/grammar you provided. Can you post enough code (and example input) so that others can reproduce this? If not, I don't see how anyone can help you with this.

Comment: I will make example of code later.

Comment: I added example on github

Answer (score 1):

Your error is likely in the way you are constructing your lexer and/or input stream (i.e. code that you have not shown here). The predicate you describe above will work as expected for an ANTLR 4 lexer.

Also, if `getCharPositionInLine()==0`, then exactly one of the following conditions is also true:

1. `_input.index()==0`
2. `_input.LA(-1)=='\n'`

Comment: I wrote my editor by this tutorial http://wiki.netbeans.org/New_Language_Support_Tutorial_Antlr

Comment: @DAiMor, as Sam already mentioned: the predicate is fine, your problem most likely originates from another rule/code-block in your grammar.

Comment: I noticed that, while editing text editor sent to lexer not all text but only changed, and in this fragment working lexer. I don't know how change it.